# Setting FPU rounding direction from Rust and C++ changes nothing

Tags: c++, floating-point, rust, rounding, computation

In my understanding, setting the rounding direction toward `+Inf` will yield `0.333334` when evaluating 1/3, and `0.33333` when setting it toward `-Inf`.

That is not the case when I tried in C++ using `fesetround(0x400)` and `fesetround(0x800)`. I get the same behavior in Rust using FFI to call `fsetround` from C.

C++ code:

```
#include <cfenv>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    double ratio = (double)1/(double)10;
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    cout << fegetround() << " upward " << setprecision(18) <<  ratio << std::endl;
    fesetround(FE_DOWNWARD);
    cout << fegetround() << " downward " << setprecision(18) << ratio << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/WQjHwaVx))

Rust code:

```
extern crate libc;

use libc::c_int;

#[link(name = "rounding")]
extern {
    pub static fe_upward: c_int;
    pub static fe_downward: c_int;
    fn fesetround(rount: c_int) -> c_int;
    fn fegetround() -> c_int;
}

pub fn upward_round() -> i64 {
    unsafe {
        fesetround(fe_upward);
        fegetround() as i64
    }
}

pub fn downward_round() -> i64 {
    unsafe {
        fesetround(fe_downward);
        fegetround() as i64
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_upward() {
        unsafe {
            assert_eq!(fe_upward as i64, upward_round());
        }
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_downward() {
        unsafe {
            assert_eq!(fe_downward as i64, downward_round());
        }
    }
}
```

([Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/zRvARfUE))

Comment: The representation is in binary, so it's not that simple. Your C++ program shows a difference in the last digit for the two rounding modes, so it seems to be working.

Comment: for me the output of the c++ program is : 0.1000000....006 for both representations. I understand that the floating point representation due to its limitation can represent only a subset of real numbers, normally 1/3 in real is 0.33333...etc. to be represented in floating point need to round it, when i set the rounding toward +inf i expect to get 0.333334.

Comment: I get `0.100000000000000006` and `0.100000000000000005` for one tenth, and `0.333333333333333315` and `0.333333333333333314` for one third.

Comment: I don't get the the same results on my desktop computer (windows 10 i7 4790 (from memory)), for 1/3 i get  0.333333333333333315 for both upward and downward, and for 1/10 i get 0.100000000000000006 for both rounding direction. Maybe it is platform dependent.

Comment: `g++ (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2` here.

Comment: It worked for me when I used the [`_controlfp(mask,rounding)`](http://systemmanager.ru/svcsunix.en/extfile/sir/_controlfp.htm) function from the `float.h` file.

Comment: gcc 5.3.0 clang 3.8 rust 1.10 nightly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starblue's comment is right, but let me expand it.

"Rounding" means approximating a real number by a finite set of digits, in some unspecified base. Your example 1/3 = 0.333333 assumes rounding to 6 *decimal* digits, i.e. base 10.

Computers work in base 2, however. Binary 1/11 is `.1010101010101...` As you can see, rounding this is a bit peculiar. If you round to nearest to 6 bits, it would be `.101011` and if you round it to 7 bits it's `.1010100` - the last bit is always the same as the penultimate bit, and that's because the bits alternate.

Round up and round down is simpler, of course. Rounding `.10101010...` down simply truncates the result to N bits: `0.101010`. And rounding up merely adds 1 to the last bit.

Now you do the rounding in binary, but you print the result in decimal. That means that these patterns aren't obvious at all.

Here's where things get complicated": Rounding is needed almost everywhere in FP functions, so it should be fast. That means you'd want the rounding mode compiled in. But you can't recompile your code on every call to `fesetround`. That means a compromise is needed, and the compromise is [`#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv). If it's `ON`, you get the slow code and `fesetround` works. If it's off (the default), `fesetround` has **unspecified** results.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. If the `#pragma STDC FENV_ACCESS` is off how could I set the rounding mode at compile time?.

Comment: @Houss_gc: No idea; you I don't know which compiler you have. Check your manual.

Comment: Ok (sorry for that dumb question :p ) actually I am using gcc 5.3.0, clang 3.8 (both under Msys2) and Rust 1.10 nightly. I will check the manual of those and see what i can do, thank you again.

Comment: @Houss_gc: There's a remarkable lack of magic in computers. The numerical code that performs the rounding is compiled by either gcc, clang or Rust, and you presumably know which.