Is there a way to control the rounding strategy when parsing floats?
Here is some parsing results from running this code:
let print_and_parse = |s| println!("{} => {:.0}", s, f64::from_str(s).unwrap());

string               f64
18014398509481991 => 18014398509481992
18014398509481992 => 18014398509481992
18014398509481993 => 18014398509481992
18014398509481994 => 18014398509481992
18014398509481995 => 18014398509481996
18014398509481996 => 18014398509481996
18014398509481997 => 18014398509481996
18014398509481998 => 18014398509482000
18014398509481999 => 18014398509482000
18014398509482000 => 18014398509482000

It appears that Rust is using a "ties-to-even" style of strategy where it alternates rounding up and down at halfway points. In the table above it shows ...1994 rounds down to ...1992 while ...1998 rounds up to ...2000 even when ...1996 is an equidistant choice for both.
Is there a way to get a different rounding strategy? I'd like a "ties-to-zero" strategy if at all possible.

Maybe this will help? https://stackoverflow.com/q/36681157/ (the code example how they use C functions to switch rounding mode for a block).

"ties-to-zero" strategy  is quite unusual.  Sure you want that?

Maybe look  at the implementation in std? Seems like copy-pasting the dec2flt and write a round-to-zero version of biased_fp_to_float would solve the problem.

these are system settings and are often broken; might need to "roll your own"
